# mat-prefix to work on the input not the label

Tags: css, angular-material, angular6

So using material we have some code to ask a question, the input we would like to add a $ sign to the front of or use a place holder. inside of this mat field we also have a mat-label. If I use matprefix it puts the dollar sign infront of the label not the input field. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always" class="fb-form-field fb-auto-detail-question-group">
        <!-- <mat-label class="fb-question-label">Amount of service or tow? </mat-label> -->
        <label class="sub">What was the amount of the service or tow bill?<span class="frm__label--required">*</span></label>
        <input matInput formControlName="serviceBillAmount" class="fb-form-auto-input"  />
        <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
        <mat-error *ngIf="fieldInvalid('serviceBillAmount')"> The dollar amount you entered is invalid. Please try again.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding this too much, you are trying to replicate the behavior show in this example? https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#prefix-amp-suffix

Comment: @IvanS95 Yes, however when I attempt to do it, the $ is applied to the label rather than the input.

Comment: So you say that the icon goes up with the label or something like that? If possible try to provide an stackblitz example reproducing your issue

Comment: @IvanS95 This is what it is doing, I didn't bother with Css, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2qti1

Comment: Great, I think I might have an idea for what's going on, but it'll be better to work on your actual code, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this example, try comparing that with your code, `matPrefix` and `matSuffix` should not collide with any labels placed on the form field. Keep in mind since you are using Angular Material you should stick to the structures provided in the framework, in this case, you should use a `mat-label` tag instead of just `label`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4eagb

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2qti1, any idea why my code is not working the same way?

Comment: Oh! I see now, you are using `label`, you should use `mat-label` instead

Comment: I see the same thing it messed up the current css but should  fix the issue. @IvanS95

Comment: I see you had it commented out, any particular reason for that??

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me after spending so much time.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Amount</mat-label>
    <span matPrefix>$ &nbsp;</span>
    <input matInput placeholder="0" formControlName="amount">
</mat-form-field>
```

**CSS**

```
.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-infix{
    position: initial;
}
.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label-wrapper{
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: `.mat-form-field-infix { position: initial; }` and `label { left: 16px; }` did the trick to allow dynamic prefix width 